Showing $a^2+b^2+c^2 \le 9R^2$, where $R$ is the circumradius of a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$

Given a triangular $\triangle ABC$ and $R$ is circumradius of $\triangle ABC$. Prove that
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+c^2 \le 9R^2 \tag1
\end{align}

My proof: We know that $a = 2R \sin A$
So
$$(1)\Leftrightarrow 4R^2(\sin^2A + \sin^2 B + \sin^2 C) \le 9R^2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sin^2A + \sin^2 B + \sin^2 C \le \dfrac{9}{4} \tag2$$
We need to prove $(2)$ is true.
We have
$$ \sin^2A + \sin^2 B + \sin^2 C = \dfrac{1 - 2\cos A}{2} + \dfrac{1 - 2\cos B}{2} + 1 - \cos^2 C$$
$$ = 2 - (\cos 2A + \cos 2B) - \cos^2 C$$
$$ = 2 - \cos(A+B)\cos(A-B) - \cos^2 C$$
$$ = 2 - \cos C \cos(A-B) - \cos^2 C$$
$\triangle ABC$ triangular $$\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} \cos C > 0 \\\ 
 0 < \cos(A-B) \le 1 \end{cases}$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos C \cos(A-B) \le \cos C$$
$$\Rightarrow LHS_{(2)} \le 2 + \cos C - \cos^2C = \dfrac{9}{4} - \left(\cos C - \dfrac{1}{2} \right)^2 \le \dfrac{9}{4}$$
So we are done
The inequality holds $a = b = c$ or $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral triangle
However, in my opinion, it isn't a nice solution!
I am looking for a nice solution. Any idea? (sorry for my bad English)

Shouldn't it be $\cos2A$ and $\cos2B$ in the equation with $\sin^2A + \sin^2 B + \sin^2 C$  as the LHS?

you mean R is the radius of the circumcircle?

This is a well know result. I expect it to be a duplicate..

An Approach0.xyz search for the inequality yields many results from Math.SE and ArtOfProblemSolving.com.

@Gwen yes R is the radius of the circumcircle

@Blue Approacho.xyz search is so impressive! Many thanks for your help.

COMMENT.-What do you mean by "nice solution" other than yours? I have a distint answer but I think yours is nicer and easier. Any way there is a a graphical solution in the attached figure which is (I think) nicer and easier than yours..

